# Transposing output of xml into columns and save it to a Dataframe

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read a xml file and convert it to a csv file.

I have manage to extract the contents of the xml file as part of a for loop. I am trying to have this stored in columns rather than rows as it is currently stored. Given below is how my data looks like:

```
Date - 2019-01-01T08:00:00
ID - 5601986
Description - Product A
Product Type - 

ProductCode - ABC
ProductName - Computer

RefID - X-123
Comments -
```

Expected Output:

```
Date,ID,Description,ProductCode,ProductName,RefID,Comments
2019-01-01T08:00:00,5601986, Product A,ABC,Computer,X-123,
```

Code that I have built thus far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('/users/desktop/file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root:
    print(elem.tag, '-', elem.text)
    for subelem in elem:
        print(subelem.tag, '-', subelem.text)
```

I am trying to have this converted to a Dataframe for further analysis

**Update:**

*Including the new xml file:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CISDocument>
  <Name>Type</Name>
  <Code>ABC</Code>
  <Description>Done</Description>
  <SystemTimeZoneOffset>0.000000</SystemTimeZoneOffset>
  <RefDate>2018-12-26T17:42:59</RefDate>
  <ReportedDateTime>2018-12-26T17:43:00</ReportedDateTime>
  <OccurredDateTime>2018-12-26T17:43:12</OccurredDateTime>
  <Customer>
    <Customerpin>XYZ</Customerpin>
    <CustomerName>Hello</CustomerName>
  </Customer>
</CISDocument>
```

Current Output:

```
Customerpin,CustomerName
XYZ,Hello
```

Comment: could you show your xml file (some elements)?

Comment: @Frenchy I have included a view of the xml file in my initial post, hope that helps.

Comment: hum i have an error during the parsing, the fact Product type has a space?

Comment: @Frenchy my bad, it was a typo from my side while pasting the xml script..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way (getchildren deprecated):

and i use yield in case of big xml

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import io

def iter_docs(cis):
    for docall in cis:
        doc_dict = {}
        for doc in docall:
            tag = [elem.tag for elem in doc]
            txt = [elem.text for elem in doc]
            if len(tag) > 0: doc_dict.update(dict(zip(tag, txt)))
            else:
                doc_dict[doc.tag] = doc.text
        yield doc_dict

#sample with 2 records
xml_data = io.StringIO(u'''\
<CISDocument>
    <REC>
        <Date>LoadStopConfirmed</Date>
        <ID>5601986</ID>
        <Description>Product A</Description>
        <ProductType>
            <ProductCode>ABC</ProductCode>
            <ProductName>Computer</ProductName>
        </ProductType>
        <RefID>X-123</RefID> 
        <Comments>Product A</Comments>  
    </REC>
    <REC>
        <Date>other</Date>
        <ID>5601987</ID>
        <Description>Product B</Description>
        <ProductType>
            <ProductCode>DEF</ProductCode>
            <ProductName>Computer</ProductName>
        </ProductType>
        <RefID>X-124</RefID>
        <Comments>Product B</Comments>
    </REC>
</CISDocument>
''')


etree = ET.parse(xml_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(etree.getroot())))
print(df)
```

output:

```
    Comments               Date Description  ... ProductCode ProductName  RefID
0  Product A  LoadStopConfirmed   Product A  ...         ABC    Computer  X-123
1  Product B              other   Product B  ...         DEF    Computer  X-124
[2 rows x 7 columns]
```

If you want to apply that on multiple xml file, just put the list of file in list and do that

```
xml_data = "E:/test.xml"

df = pd.DataFrame()      #create the final df empty

#here i use a list of same file 
xmllist =  [xml_data, xml_data, xml_data]
for xmlfile in xmllist:
    etree = ET.parse(xmlfile).getroot()
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(etree)))
    df = df.append(tmp)

print(df)
```

Comment: I am trying to figure a way to concat multiple xml files into a single Dataframe. Could you please help me edit the above code such that I am able to perform this task. Thanks

Comment: if i understand you, you want to have to use the same program for more xml, from my example , i suppose i have xml_data1 and xml_data2 (same structure) and merge in same df?

Comment: I have say 10 xml files in a folder, I am trying to have them all merged to single df

Comment: ok i just adapt the loop, its not complex, i put the name of xml in list

Comment: I tried to modify the path defined in line `etree = ET.parse(xml_data)` however it threw and error `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list`.. So I was wondering if this is something wrong from my side..

Comment: see my modification to apply on multiple xml files

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
final = []
for elem in root:
    temp = {}
    for i in elem.getchildren():
        if i:
            for c in i.getchildren():
                temp[c.tag] = c.text
        else:
            temp[i.tag] = i.text
    final.append(temp)

df = pd.DataFrame(final)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Comments               Date Description       ID ProductCode ProductName  \
0           LoadStopConfirmed   Product A  5601986         ABC    Computer   

   RefID  
0  X-123
```

---

**New XML file:**

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
final = {}
for elem in root:
    if len(elem):
        for c in elem.getchildren():
            final[c.tag] = c.text
    else:
        final[elem.tag] = elem.text

df = pd.DataFrame([final])
print(df)
```

Comment: thank you this helped. Could I ask for another favor. Is there a way we could make the above code generic. Instead of hard coding "ProductType" is it possible to keep it as a variable to call all sub-nodes as part of the loop.. Thanks again

Comment: thanks for your edit.. I tried with a new xml file and found that it returns output of the children however the values in the leaf level do not get returned.. I have posted the file I tried to run this script along with the output that it returned as part of my initial post.. See this seems to occur on all xml files so wanted to check with you on the same. Thanks.